# neo4j multiple cypher compatibility

Tags: neo4j, cypher, version

Neo4J's Cypher has a [compatibility](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/introduction/compatibility/) feature that lets you specify which Cypher version you want to use. ect, `CYPHER 3.2 CREATE (:TEST)`. My queries are limited such that I know they are compatible with 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2 (3.* really). I want to make sure Neo4J will only run 3.*, but it seems I can only specify one or non.

One solution to support multiple versions is to try to run the query with each version set, until one doesn't throw an error, but that seems horribly crude/inefficient. So is there a better way to make Cypher queries run only 3.* or 3.0-3.2? (Better defined as I only need to ask Neo4J once to do the query, regardless of which version of Neo4J is actually being hit, and it just works or fails like if I only allowed 3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can only specify `2.3`, `3.1` or `3.2` after the `CYPHER` statement. Or you can set `2.3`, `3.1`, `3.2` or `default` in the option [cypher.default_language_version](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_cypher.default_language_version) of `neo4j.conf` file.

> One solution to support multiple versions is to try to run the query
>   with each version set, until one doesn't throw an error, but that
>   seems horribly crude/inefficient.

Unfortunately, seems to me this is the only alternative... :(